# Android Facebook Logout Crash

Tags: android, facebook, logout

I have copied the logout code off of Facebook's android tutorial. Every time I try to logout I get a null pointer exception.

Here is the code...

```
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
```

...

```
              mAsyncRunner.logout(home.this, new RequestListener() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(String response, Object state) 
              {
                 /* mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("firstTime", true).commit();
                  userName.setText("Logged out!");*/
              }

              @Override
              public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                  Log.d("IOExcenption", e.toString());
              }

              @Override
              public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
                  Log.d("FileNotFoundException", e.toString());
              }

              @Override
              public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
                  Log.d("MalformedUrlExpection", e.toString());
              }

              @Override
              public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                  Log.d("FacebookError", e.toString());
              }
            });
```

Log

```
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011): java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at rageup.android.home.onClick(home.java:177)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 04-29 23:41:35.523: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 04-29 23:41:35.534: I/dalvikvm(1011): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
 04-29 23:41:35.534: E/dalvikvm(1011): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
 04-29 23:41:37.283: I/Process(1011): Sending signal. PID: 1011 SIG: 9
```

Any suggestions for why this might be happening? The Null Pointer exception is referring to the first line of the second block of code.

Comment: where is your **LOGCAT**? would you post it? And also check that your `Home.this` is not a null pointer

Comment: put up the log, and just checked if home.this is null, it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `mAsyncRunner` seems to be `null`.

Have you initialized it?

initialize it something like this:

```
mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);  //mFacebook is your facebook object.
```

Comment: I have not, what would I initialize it to?

Answer (score 0):

try below code,

```
public void logout(final Context context,
                   final RequestListener listener,
                   final Object state) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override public void run() {
            try {
                String response = fb.logout(context);
                if (response.length() == 0 || response.equals("false")){
                    listener.onFacebookError(new FacebookError(
                            "auth.expireSession failed"), state);
                    return;
                }
                listener.onComplete(response, state);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                listener.onFileNotFoundException(e, state);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                listener.onMalformedURLException(e, state);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                listener.onIOException(e, state);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void logout(final Context context, final RequestListener listener) {
    logout(context, listener, /* state */ null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether context is null or not and try to use

```
 facebook.logout(this);
```